# How long it usually takes for Openshift alias remove to take effect?

Tags: dns, openshift

I'm having a bit of trouble with knowing how long would it take for a `rhc alias remove` to  take effect.

That is, when I access the domain aliased before it still points to the old site, moreso when the CNAME is update in domain manager (like GoDaddy), access to site is causing a certificate error.

And also it loads something like `https://wwwm.my-old-domain-before.com/app` where its opening this /app which I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like more of a DNS issue.  It could take up to 24-48 hours for the dns to update.  Expecially if you re-used the same application name.